# How can I use the rear facing camera on video conferencing apps like Skype and Zoom?

Tags: iphone, camera, skype, zoom.app

I use an iPhone 8. By default, Skype and Zoom use the front camera. But my rear camera has higher resolution and quality, correct? How can I order video conferencing apps like Skype and Zoom to use the rear camera?

[image]

Comment: One issue here is that even if you do get the app to use the rear camera, the rear camera needs to face you to be useful. This means the screen will be facing away from you, in which case you won't be able to see the other participants.

Comment: @abligh that assumes that you want to show your face.  It could be useful in a conference call to also be able to show your surroundings at times.

Comment: Unless both your + their internet connections are very good, it’s unlikely you’re going get any significant improvement from using the better camera. Plus any compression the app your using applies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zoom has the ability to switch cameras in the iOS app.  The switch is available in the top left of the screen once you have started a meeting.  It does not appear that you can select the rear camera before you start the meeting;  so you will always have a moment where the front camera is "on" before you switch to the rear camera.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If the app itself doesn't support it, you can't do it. It's the code of the app that determines which camera is to be used. There is no system-wide setting to override this.

I don't have Zoom, but Skype does have the option to switch cameras; there's an icon in the top right corner which does this:

[image]